# Data is not writing into csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am doing a basic scraping where to scrape all p tags in a webpage. And I am writing them into a csv file. The csv contains only 1 row(item name only).  I am using Google Colab. Code forcraping works well. But when I try to open the csv file, I get the following error.

```
Row given with size different than 1 (the number of columns in the table)
```

This is my try:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding= 'utf8', newline='') as f:
   thewriter = writer(f)
   header = ['itemname']
   thewriter.writerow(header)

   for link in catagorylinks:
     newr = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(newr.content, 'html.parser')

     for p in soup.find_all('p' , class_='item-name'):
       item = (p.text)
       print(item)
       thewriter.writerow(item)
```

I can't figure out what the issue is. Can someone please explain where I get wrong?

Comment: I guess you want `thewriter.writerow([item])`

Comment: csv looks like a bad file type for what you're doing: you just have one column and if the html you're scraping is well formed, then paragraphs are just random text, full of column separators like spaces and commas

Comment: Your code should include the imports needed as well.  Not everyone may be familiar with the `csv` or `bs4` modules.

Comment: @buran It worked! Thank you